# Can't use mysql commands in terminal OS X

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal

I can't really understand how to handle with MySQL from terminal. I need to check and change password, and hostname but even simple commands fail except `mysql --version`

I tried

```
$   sudo mysql -u root -p
```

and also:

```
$ PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin.
```

Get this error

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

or

```
$   sudo sh -c 'echo /usr/local/mysql/bin > /etc/paths.d/mysql'
$   mysql
```

In this case:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'Robert'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

What is wrong? What is the right way to handle with MySQL? OS X 10.11

The password is right. However I tried to change it like in the last answer here superuser.com/questions/123275/… but received error :

```
 `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)`
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to reset the password for root. See here for instructions https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: I can't get access to mysql command line. The password is right. However I tried to change like in the last answer here http://superuser.com/questions/123275/how-do-i-reset-my-root-password-on-mysql-on-a-mac 
but received error : Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: Does the output of the command `code` ps -ef | grep 'mysql' `code` show it's running?